# image gets scrunched from inheriting font-size property

Tags: html, css

I'm having this problem where the the image (pics/headphoto.jpg) inherits the font-size of the parent class. I did not see this problem while testing code locally.However, when I pushed it to github the photo always gets squished to width: 197.5px from width: 600px. When I turn the font-size property on/off on the console the image size returns to normal.  Please advise how I should resolve this problem. Thanks

HTML

```
    <h3 class="well"><img src="pics/headphoto.jpg"> 
<br><br><div>We know the Internet is a jumbled mess to navigate so we're here to boost your online presence. <br><br> Our remote webcam tutorials are fast, flexible and fun, and will turn your headscratching computer experiences into high-fiving woohoo moments. We offer a wide range of computer tutorials from social media to email, and tailor our courses to meet your skill level.<br><br> Here's our guarantee to you: we'll conduct a 30 minute session free of charge to learn your needs. Then you decide whether to continue.
</div></h3>
```

CSS

```
.well {
  display:flex;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

h3.well{
  width:95%; 
  height:590px; 
  margin-left:20px; 
  margin-top:20px;
  font-size:30px;
  padding:40px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  max-height: 600px;
  font-size:30px;
}

h3.well img{
   float:left; 
   height: 500px; 
   width:600px; 
   padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px; 
   border-radius: 20px;
   font-size:0px;
}
```

Comment: This is very ill-formed HTML. Do not use divs in headings, and you definitely should be able to get rid of those br's. Finally, the better approach would probably be to set the image as a background image.

Comment: So don't put containers for elements at the top of a page? I am just learning coding so please have patience with me

Comment: also, why set the image as a background image? I would only like the image on the top of the page.